# Are questions regarding subliminal messages appropriate?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

Subliminal messages are usually associated with psychology but using AI with photo editing software creates the ability to be very creative with visual messages. Is this an appropriate topic for the Philosophy SE. I have asked quite few questions that have been viewed as off topic and I don't want to clutter the site.

Comment: Was really afraid to read this one. Man, I suddenly want a Schlitz! Weird.

Comment: @ScottRowe You were supposed to have a sudden desire to send me all your money. Clearly my subliminal messaging algorithm needs some fine tuning.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is off topic. In fact nearly all AI issues are off topic here. AI is nothing more than an advanced computational system. Any impact on society or individuals is an issue of psychology or sociology or a matter of legislation.

Comment: I think I'll start a very subtle campaign to get AI things to be on-topic. Let's see, what can I ask about...?

Comment: I guess I am not understanding how you mean that AI issues are not on-topic. Did you see my recent Question regarding ChatGPT? The question probably belonged on meta, but there it is. AI will at least impinge on Ethics if nothing else. I agree that basically no one understands the technology. People were fooled by Eliza 60 years ago.

Comment: @ScottRowe In the current climate, any philosophical issues regarding AI (and I don't believe there any) are completely dwarfed by the Psychology of AI: Fear and uncertainty of our dominance in the food chain. Fear and uncertainty about a technology that is also a marketable product with AI becoming the new buzzword. Meanwhile, the general public is unsure of what this technology actually does.  It's too muddled to make sense of any philosophical ramifications.

Comment: @ScottRowe I believe many of the philosophical issues regarding AI have already been addressed during the Industrial Revolution. The difference is mental rather than physical replacement.

Comment: @ScottRowe I worry more about hacking and deliberate human corruption of AI software for nefarious purposes but this is really nothing new from a philosophical standpoint. From a simple perspective, AI is a new type of weapon.

Comment: "*Weapon and gem, doslem, doslem*". We are creating golems. We have to be able to say "*Klaatu barada nictu!*" or we'll be in trouble.

Comment: @ScottRowe The hardware that runs AI is fundamentally no different than your cell phone or PC so AI can't really go much further until a sigficant hardware change takes place.  The reason chimpanzees are not as intelligent as humans is about both "hardware" and "software".